# Load objects from db by parameter Date

Tags: database, hibernate, date, entity, entitymanager

I have some objects in db. Every object has parameter Date in date format like a "Mon Oct 05 08:55:36 CEST 2015". I want load all objects from 24h before to present time. I am using hibernate entity manager. Can you help me please

Here is my entity params:

```
private Long id;
private String email;
private String answer1;
private String answer2;
private Date date;
```

Here is table schema:

```
ID ;  email ;           answer1 ;   answer2 ;   date
1  ;  any@thing.com ;     1234  ;      4321 ;   2015-10-04 18:01:19
```

Comment: What's the DB? Please post the DB table schema and the entity (at least limited to the date field you are interested in)

Comment: Database is MySQL. Table schema and entity I send for a few hours until I get to the PC, where my project is saved

Comment: I suggest you edit the original post - will be more readable

Comment: One more thing then - can you post the table SQL schema? That is, the output of `describe <the table name>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume then, that the type of the `date` table column is indeed SQL `DATE`. In that case, you can simply run a HQL/JPQL query

```
SELECT e FROM YourEntity e WHERE e.date BETWEEN :from AND :to
```

Make a PreparedStatement out of it and provide the desired values for the `from` and `to` parameters. Sample using JPA:

```
EntityManager em = ...;

Date to = new Date();
Calendar fromCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
fromCalendar.setTime(to);
fromCalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -24);
Date from = fromCalendar.getTime();

em
        .createQuery("SELECT e FROM YourEntity e WHERE e.date BETWEEN :from AND :to", YourEntity.class)
        .setParameter("from", from, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        .setParameter("to", to, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        .getResultList();
```

Using [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or Java8 [Time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) may make the whole date manipulation easier (didn't know if you were using those, so I gave an example using the "basic" Java classes).

Comment: I am using basic Date class, but i will try use Java8 Time package in future. Your solution look pretty good. I will try it and let you know. Thank you